# How do I install drivers and configure my screen to work? (15.04, nvidia 760 gtx, QNIX QX2710)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.04

Every time I try to install the Nvidia drivers for my graphics card, the GTX 760, I end up with a black screen on boot which stops me from using the computer.

This happens regardless of where I download it from, it seems, as I've tried both with the Nvidia website, `apt-get` and Ubuntu Software Center. I've tried nvidia-current (349) as well as 319, with the same result from both.

I actually sat down and read Nvidia's readme as well, which simply doesn't help.

How do I install drivers that work? Could I be missing a step?

EDIT: Apparently it's not my graphics drivers that are messing with my - it's my screen. I have one of those cheap 27" 2560x1440 monitors, a QNIX QX2710, and this monitor does not report it's EDID correctly. I tried following a couple of guides but with no progress. I'll put this on hold, it's simply not worth the time and frustration.

Comment: If you don't have any proprietary NVIDIA driver installed, the command: `ubuntu-drivers devices` from the terminal will tell you the package name of the Recommended proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers might help a bit. The text refers to old drivers, but the instructions are as should be, I actually use the proprietary driver in the same manner - on 14.04.2 LTS for a GTX 780. Note that kernel and xorg updates often requires a subsequent re-install.

Comment: @Hannu I just checked the https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and the good news is, it is covered up to Ubuntu 15.04.  I have been using that repository for a while now and love it that it keeps my NVIDIA driver updated and works great with new kernel updates.  So, good answer!

Comment: @Terrance - I ran xorg-edgers up until the moment when they stepped up xorg/mesa (?) libraries beyond what I had installed - which of course broke it for me. That made me remove the ppa and use the proprietary driver instead; which has been "smooth sailing" since, just keeping in mind that kernal and xorg updates needs to be tried before letting them in fully.

Comment: @Hannu Well, I have been updating to the 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 kernels and they have been updating into the kernels without problems at all.  I know that it is not going to be the same for everybody that uses it as each situation is different, but they have been the only ones posting newer drivers where Canonical or the regular Ubuntu repositories have been outdated and not working with my 8800GT.  None the less, it is still a place to start for updated NVIDIA drivers.  They also recommend that you remove their repo before distribution upgrade.

Comment: @Jeff nvidia-current is a package name - these are case sensitive so please don't change their capitalization.

Comment: @Zanna I'm sorry, I probably didn't change the package name intentionally. I was looking for errors, so I started with the Nvidia name and was looking for Nvidia at first... I was probably not paying attention.

Comment: @Jeff no worries, thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 0):

nVidia 349 is in beta stage for Linux (according to [geforce.com](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) ). There might be a bug which is occurring your problem. nVidia 319 doesn't support GTX 760, the support for Linux came from nvidia-337. I'd recommend you to install it from Ubuntu's additional drivers. Perform the following steps:

1. Open dash and search for `Additional Drivers` [image]
2. Open Additional Drivers and select `Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.59 from nvidia-346-updates (prpprietary)`[image]
3. Click `Apply Changes`. [image]
4. After the installation, reboot your system and everything should work fine.

Comment: This results in the same behaviour as before - the screen just turns black. Could it be because of my high resolution? I'm running 2560x1440.

Comment: Have you checked if your graphics card can handle that resolution?

Comment: Maybe it can't handle it on ubuntu, but it works fine in windows and with the standard X.Org driver.

Comment: nVidia 337+ should have support for Linux.